# Opening a pre-existing form by buttonclick from mainform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have read a numerous threads about opening a preexisting form from a button click event inside a mainform/Form1 but I don't know why it won't work for me.

The code in Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DesignP1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Button3_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();

    }
   }
}
```

Form 2 is identical to Form 1 except no button event.

Comment: Dumb questions first: is `Button3_click` actually hooked up to your button? What if you replace its content with a call to `MessageBox.Show()`? Does the msgbox show up?

Comment: Problem solved
I rightclicked Button 3 in the first form and selected properties, and then selected button3_click under the action property.

Comment: I thought I was gonna answer my own question first :). 
But thanks for the reply s.m! :)

Comment: No problem, have a nice day.